# Logitech Zone Wireless Headphones Switch to HPDF even on USB

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, logitech

I recently bought a pair of Logitech Zone Wireless headphones and I'm noticing that the audio is not staying true to it's specified output configuration. For example, in pavu, I can see the following:

- Stereo Output + Mono Input
- Stereo Output
- Multichannel Output
- Multichennel Output + Mono Input

Essentially, any time I attempt to enable the use of the microphone, the sound goes to what I would describe in bluetooth terms as "HPDF mode" (crackly, lacking bass, generally poor quality audio) instead of "ADP" mode. Sound quality is significantly degraded as it it were a bluetooth device and while that's "also" its capability in this case I'm connected via USB.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the mic on the device at the same time as getting good sound. Tell me how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modes are intentional by design and appear locked together. It does not appear to be possible to have digital input with mono output. This is likely because of bluetooth. It appears that even on Windows when voice is activated the device switches into lower quality output mode. I suppose my expectation was that this device would have digital audio out and mono-in given it's USB connection (I was wrong).

On linux, you may need to use pavu-control to switch between "+mono" mode and "digital" or "analog" modes.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

This is the only way I've been able to successfully change modes. The sound device chooser in settings doesn't appear to do anything. Sometimes, especially after a hotplug of the dongle, I also need to restart pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This resets pavucontrol and shows the correct options set for the headset (or makes it show up at all).